org-store-link relative to parent
Should it be possible to org-store-link including parents of a heading. For example in a document like this:
* heading 1
** subheading 1
* heading 2
** subheading 1

there is ambiguity if you want to org-store-link to heading 2 > subheading 1. By default org stores [[file:<FILENAME>::*subheading1]], which would incorrectly point to heading 1.
You could create unique UUID in PROPERTIES, but wouldn't it be more informative if org-store-link used parent headings instead?
UPDATE Request For Enhancement has been submitted to org-mode mailing list on
Tue, 01 Oct 2024 23:25:48 +0000 (02/10/24 00:25:48)
Subject: org-store-link relative to parent headings


The docs explicitly state that the referent has to be unique. The strategy that you suggest would be harder to implement (and maybe error-prone in other ways: e.g. using regexps to match would require that you match the stuff between the heading and the subheading). Instead of UUIDs, you can use dedicated targets like <<h2-s>> or custom IDs, which still require adding a property, but they can be more  informative than UUIDs. See Internal links in the manual.

But if you feel strongly enough about it, send an RFE to the Org mode mailing list: any discussion here would be a matter of opinion.

Thanks, it's good to know that I didn't miss anything obvious and it is in fact not possible to make internal links relative to parent headings right now. I think it would be useful though, so will suggest it on the mailing list.

Please update the question (or write an answer) pointing to your RFE, when it is available. Thanks!

I've updated the question with reference to RFE, sorry I've only now realized that subject should have had [RFE] tag in it
